# On-premesis SQL Server setup for MFA against Azure AD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to set up multi-factor authentication in SSMS using an on-premesis SQL Server (Standard Edition).  I believe the SSMS is simple enough.  Under the "Login" tab, I have chosen "Active Directory - Universal with MFA support" and have my user name (like "john.doe@example.com").

[image: Login tab]

Under "Connection Properties," I put in a specific database and my Azure AD tenant ID (guid):

[image: Connection Properties tab]

When I try to log in, I get a popup from Microsoft, which I assume is the SSO login:

[image: SSO Login]

However, when I put in my password, I get error 18456, State 1:

[image: Error 18456]

I assume this is because I need to add the user on the server side.  However, I have not been able to find how to do that for an on-premesis SQL Server (there are plenty of guides for Azure SQL).  I am using Standard Edition 2017.  What do I need to do to complete the setup?

Comment: Azure AD Auth is not supported with on-premise SQL Server, only SQL Authentication and Windows Authentication are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to set up multi-factor authentication in SSMS using an on-premesis SQL Server (Standard Edition).

"Active Directory - Universal with MFA Support" is an Azure Active Directory authentication method.  SQL Server (on premises) doesn't support Azure Active Directory Authentication; it only supports SQL Auth and Windows Auth (NTLM and Kerberos).

Comment: Does the OnPremise AD DS Synched user to Azure AD can use MFA?

Comment: Yes.  That's a very common setup.